# Finding the law of X - Y when X and Y are not independent

Tags: probability, density-function

I have the following joint density: $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\frac{2}{(1+x)^3} (0<y<x) $$

I want to find the density of X - Y. Now, I found that $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{x} (0<x<\infty)$ and $ f_Y(y) = \mathbb{1} (0,x)$, so X and Y are not independent.

I want to use the following formula that gives me the density function of Z = X + Y:

$$ f_Z(z) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)dx $$

However I am not sure how should I change it to get the density of X - Y. I tried using $x - z$ instead of $z-x$ but it does not work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

No need to write down marginal densities. $P(X-Y\leq t) =\int _0^{\infty} \int _y ^{y+t} \frac 2 {(1+x)^{3}} dx dy=1-\frac 1 {1+t}$ for $t \geq 0$ and $0$ for $t <0$. Hence the density of $X-Y$ is   $\frac 1 {(1+t)^{2}}, 0<t<\infty$. [ To get the limits for integration  note that When $t >0$, $x-y < t$ and $0 <y<x$ are equivalent to $y<x<y+t$ and $ x >0$

Comment: I see. Can I say that X - Y and Y are not independent even though they have the same law because X and Y are not independent?